# ghc 7.8.4 source installation via make fails on Centos 6.6

Tags: haskell, ghc, yum

Before installing ghc on my Centos 6.6, i printed available ghc in centos repo using,

```
 yum --showduplicates list ghc | expand
```

and got,

```
ghc.x86_64                           7.0.4-46.el6                           epel
```

But since 7.0.4 is old, i downloaded `ghc-7.8.4-x86_64-unknown-linux-centos65.tar` from [haskell-downloads](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_3#x86_64linux) and did `./configure && make install`.
It gave error as,

```
Configuring ghc-prim-0.3.1.0...
ghc-cabal: Cannot find the program 'ghc' at
'/root/ghc-7.8.4/inplace/bin/ghc-stage1' or on the path
make[1]: *** [install_packages] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Comment: I would just do a complete uninstall, and redo everything. I've had to do that before.

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/QuickStart Claims that you're supposed to do `make` and then `make install`. I don't know if that's significant. It also says a few other things about tweaking `PATH` and so on...

Comment: make with no arguments fail as """make: *** [default] Error 1"""... it doesn't help... i am installing ghc and it says 'cannot find the program ghc'... ironical!

Comment: Um...  Are you installing the precompiled binary for your platform, or building from source? The two are very different, and you report having mixed the steps for the two.

Comment: since precompiled binary is very old, i completely removed all yum rpms (cleaned dependencies as well).. and tried to do source installation...

Comment: GHC is a self-hosting compiler, which means that you *must* have a precompiled binary of a reasonably recent version in order to compile it from source. In fact 7.0.4 is too old to compile 7.8.4. The 7.8.* series seems to require at least 7.4.